# Plotting val_loss and loss in Keras gives incorrect figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am running below a piece of code to plot the train and test loss curve in Keras.

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(features, target_classes , test_size=0.30)

epochs = 4
batch_size = 256

for i in range(epochs):
    print("epoch Value", i)

    ix_train = np.random.choice(train_x.shape[0], size=batch_size)

    score = model.fit(
        train_x[ix_train], train_y[ix_train]
        , epochs=1
        , validation_data=(test_x, test_y)
    )

scores.append(score)
```

//This code to plot val_loss and train_loss

```
for i in range(0, len(scores)):
    val_loss_change.append(scores[i].history['val_loss'])
    loss_change.append(scores[i].history['loss'])

plt.plot(val_loss_change, label='val_loss')
plt.plot(loss_change, label='train_loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('LossVal_loss')
```

When the plot is generated, plots values look unrealistic. Please see attached figure LossVal_loss.
I have copied  val_loss_change and loss_change from Python Debug prompt.

loss_change= : [[4.3783984780311584], [3.9744645059108734], [3.921104222536087], [3.5381810665130615], [3.3796855211257935], [3.161308079957962], [2.9224385917186737], [2.80639386177063], [2.5576193928718567], [2.1081390380859375]]

val_loss_change = :  [[4.315125052134196], [4.105147279103597], [4.0108651924133305], [3.9794070688883463], [4.025013980865478], [4.060481491088868], [4.1542660458882645], [4.011785678863525], [3.989632488886515], [4.240501753489176]]

When I simply copy val_loss_change and loss_change from pyhton Debug prompt and create a new python file and try to run it as below code.
Ploted figure is correct. Please see attached figure LossVal_loss1

```
val_loss_change = [[4.315125052134196], [4.105147279103597], [4.0108651924133305], [3.9794070688883463], [4.025013980865478], [4.060481491088868], [4.1542660458882645], [4.011785678863525], [3.989632488886515], [4.240501753489176]]
loss_change = [[4.3783984780311584], [3.9744645059108734], [3.921104222536087], [3.5381810665130615], [3.3796855211257935], [3.161308079957962], [2.9224385917186737], [2.80639386177063], [2.5576193928718567], [2.1081390380859375]]

plt.plot(val_loss_change, label='val_loss')
plt.plot(loss_change, label='train_loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('LossVal_loss1')





Can anyone tell what goes wrong in 1st code?
I want to run fit function multiple times and then plot a curve for loss and val_loss.




  [1 Correct Figure from 2nd code ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVg4o.png
  [2 Incorrect Figure from 1st Code ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcRSE.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting the model with 1 epoch over and over. Change **epochs** to the total value of epochs and delete the extra loop.  I'm on mobile so I can't test the code now.

For better and dynamic graphs use TensorBoard